# auto-py-exe - unable to convert (.py) script - "One binary added with two internal names"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Got the following errors.
What's wrong? Why is this error "One binary added with two internal names" flashing up? Is there any conflict?

```
17175 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
17971 WARNING: lib not found: python35.dll dependency of C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sip.pyd
27100 INFO: Looking for eggs
27100 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.dll
27100 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
27100 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\auto-py-to-exe-master\build\Image Processor\warn-Image Processor.txt
27196 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\auto-py-to-exe-master\build\Image Processor\xref-Image Processor.html
27230 INFO: checking PYZ
27230 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
27230 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\auto-py-to-exe-master\build\Image Processor\PYZ-00.pyz
28279 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\auto-py-to-exe-master\build\Image Processor\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
28295 INFO: checking PKG
28295 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
28295 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
28720 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
28720 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\Users\\Arvind1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
28720 WARNING: was placed previously at
28720 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\Users\\Arvind1\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the PyInstaller 3.4 release, I was getting this WARNING too. (At least the part about `One binary added with two internal names` and `libGLESv2.dll`/`PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll`.) On the `develop` branch of the project ([this is a known working commit at the time of this post](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/commit/d7405248998c89e75c8963f267c0ddad333889e4)), this WARNING still appears, but at least my project builds successfully now.